# how to change title on Next and Previous button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube-api

I am fetching Youtube videos into carousal which has next and previous button. I have also added the demo link ..

how to change title, Description, Total Views on Next and Previous button ?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){});

var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/cZxy-GpHLCQ_Ss9sGJfWhzBAIOMDYxMN?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
var list_data="";
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
var url = videoURL + videoID;
var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
list_data += '<div><a href= "#" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><img src="'+ thumb +'" width="213px" height="141px"/></a></div>';
});
$(list_data).appendTo(".slides");
$('.carousel').carousel({carouselWidth:930,carouselHeight:330,directionNav:true,shadow:true,buttonNav:'bullets'});

var cnt = 0;
$(".nextButton").click(function () {
var len = $(this).siblings(".slides").children(".slideItem").length;
var a = cnt++;



  });

});
</script>
```

here is the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/EzKQy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the properties provided by the library,

You can select the top most item based on two css attributes :

- Item with `top` = `0px`
- Item with `z-index` = `<Total Slides-1>`

So the following snippet should do it (& update the title as well) :

```
var $items = $(".slides").find(".slideItem");
$(".nextButton, .prevButton").click(function () {
$("#title").text($items.filter(function () {
        return $(this).css("top") == "0px";
   }).find("a").attr("title"));
});
```

And here is your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzKQy/2/).

Answer (score 0):

According to youtube API v2,

```
> The API response for a playlist feed is almost identical to a typical
> video feed or set of search results. However, a video entry in a
> playlist feed differs from a typical video entry in the following
> ways:
> 
> Each playlist entry contains the <yt:position> tag, which specifies
> the place that the video appears in the playlist order. The
> <yt:position> tag is a subtag of the <entry> tag.
> 
> If the user defined a custom title for the video, that title appears
> in the <atom:title> tag, and the video's original title appears in the
> <media:title> tag.
```

So the solution to the problem would be to get yt:position of the title from the JSON recieved
Hook your next button to yt:position of the next sibling and previous button to previous sibling.
You can also be creative and go for random shuffle of videos based on this.